# How to get a reference to an object in Python set

Tags: python, set

Suppose I have a set which contains objects.

```
class C(object):
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value
    def __repr__(self):
        return 'C({}):{}'.format(self.value, id(self))
    def __eq__(self, other):
        return self.value == other.value
    def __hash__(self):
        return hash(self.value)

cset = {C(1), C(2)}
print 'cset:', cset

cset: set([C(1):140241436167120, C(2):140241436167184])
```

I want to find an object in the set, and get a reference to the object.

```
c1 = C(1)
print 'c1:', c1

found, = cset & {c1}
print 'way1 found:', found
found, = {c1} & cset
print 'way2 found:', found

c1: C(1):140241436167248
way1 found: C(1):140241436167248
way2 found: C(1):140241436167248
```

Those ways are no good; return the reference to c1 (id=140241436167248), not to the object (id=140241436167120) in the set.

Just to show what I want, quick and dirty way is like this.

```
found, = [x for x in cset if x == c1]
print 'way3 found:', found

way3 found: C(1):140241436167120
```

This way returns what I wanted, the reference to the object (id=140241436167120) in the set.
But it is using linear search. Is there any better way?

Comment: You already have reference `c1` in the `set` when you do `x == c1`. All you will do is to take the same reference to `c1` from `set`. Why you want to do that?

Comment: `c1` *is* the object in the set. I really can't tell what you are asking.

Comment: What do you mean exactly by "return the reference". *Everything* is a reference to an object in Python.

Comment: As far as the set is concerned, you already have that element. It's `c1`. If you need to distinguish between `c1` and the object in the set with the same `value`, a set is the wrong data structure to use. Consider a map from values to objects.

Comment: @DanielRoseman -- No it isn't.  OP has overridden `__hash__` and `__eq__` so that `c1` could be a different (but equivalent) object.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that you're trying to use your `set` like a mapping.  That's not going to work very well...

Instead, don't make your objects explicitly hashible.  If you have a uniqueness constraint, use a dictionary to map the values to instances rather than a set.  A dictionary can enforce uniqueness just as easily as a `set` and it provides the mapping behavior that you desire.

```
if c1.value in cdict:
    c1 = cdict[c1.value]  # Trade in the `c1` we have for one already in `cdict`
```

Additionally, using a `dict` is less "clever" which is almost always a win from a readability standpoint.